# Can a SWIFT message have Arabic characters in it?

Tags: banking, onlinebanking, core-banking

I'm trying to generate a swift message with customer name and account details. Customer name sometime has only Arabic letters in it. So trying to find if this is right way. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: not technical in swift, but main issues with using Arabic with English text is alignment and whether the characters are joined up. What have you tried so far, do you have any screen grabs?

Comment: by characers joined up - I mean words being split by letter (like English) so the word house البيت being split like ا ل ب ي ت making it unintelligible

Comment: Could you please share the analysis in more eloborative manner so the community can be  help in this in more appropriate manner